# What is the cause for “panic: free from wrong pool during global destruction.” in Term::ReadLine::Gnu?

Tags: perl, crash, gdb

in https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=37194#txn-641389 I reopened a bug concerning a Perl crash in conjunction with the libreadline XS bindings. I attached the necessary debug information, but until now there has been no acknowledgement from the maintainer. I want this finally fixed; it's a major inconvenience to not have readline in [Devel::REPL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Devel::REPL) and the Perl debugger. My Perl guts and C夫 is nearly non-existent, so I can't do the usual thing and produce a patch on my own. So I would like to employ your help; more eyeballs ↔ shallow bugs and all that.

My questions to you:

1. Can you reproduce this crash despite `-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV`? If yes, let's compare what is the common factor.
2. Do you know what is the cause and how do you go about finding it?
3. I have a debugging perl and know how to use gdb, but where do I have to set a breakpoint to observe the crash properly?

Comment: Do I have a way to access the debug information without having to sign up for an account on rt.cpan.org? I'd love to look at it but hate having to register for things.

Comment: Viewing tickets and attachments are publicly accessible.

Comment: I see. (Apparently it required cookies; my default policy was cookies disabled, and requesting attachments caused me to be sent to a login page instead. :-P)

Comment: You get that error when you cause Armageddon and clean the wrong gene pool.

Comment: Quick q. daxim: is you application multi-threaded, and multithreading at or around the time of the error?

Comment: I have no application. The T::R::G tests already crash. Minimal case for panic: `perl -Mblib -MTerm::ReadLine -e'Term::ReadLine->new'`. As you can see, no threads involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that my perl never had safe putenv. The option is not `-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV`, but `-Accflags="-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV"`.

Doc patches to combat the mistake:

- https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=59592
- https://rt.perl.org/rt3/Ticket/Display.html?id=76618

Answer (score 1):

`readline 6.1.000` works fine for me here with Perl 5.10.0 & 5.10.1 (on Mac OS X 10.4, 10.5 & 10.6).

Also OK for me is Perl 5.8.8 & 5.10.1 on RedHat Enterprise Linux 5.3 (this time with `readline 5.1`).

There seems to be a lot of [bug fixes](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/CHANGES) between 5.2 & 6.1, so it might be worth trying the newer (or older!) `readline` to 5.2

/I3az/

Comment: Tried a number of different readline versions, panics irrespective.