# Perlbrew - installing Term::ReadLine::Gnu on OS X

Tags: macos, perl, macports, perlbrew, libreadline

Trying installing `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` on OS X. `make test` returns errors, like:

```
t/00checkver.t .. 1/3 panic: free from wrong pool, 62696c2f62696c!=7f8ed2801200 during global destruction.
```

After a searching found an advice compile perl with `-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV`. So, tried the next:

```
perlbrew install perl-5.16.3 --thread --multi --debug -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV
```

Need threads because the `Padre` needs them. Unfortunately, recompile doesn't helps and getting the same error. Next, I found this [What is the cause for “panic: free from wrong pool during global destruction.” in Term::ReadLine::Gnu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156286/what-is-the-cause-for-panic-free-from-wrong-pool-during-global-destruction-i) question, and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298436/771480) suggest to use: `-Accflags="-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV"`.

The questions are:

- mainly, how to get a working Term::ReadLine::Gnu on OS X with `perlbrew`?
- how to compile/install/switch the perl with `perlbrew` to getting working perl for the `Padre`, what needs `Term::ReadLine::Gnu`.

Only wondering:

- if the perl needs some "SAFE_PUTENV" for compile some CPAN modules, why is it not ON default? Why someone want a perl where isn't possible compile some CPAN modules?
- have someone working `Padre` & `perlbrew` on OS X?

If someone needs:

My perl version

```
$ perl -V
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=13.0.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin medvedik.local 13.0.0 darwin kernel version 13.0.0: thu sep 19 22:22:27 pdt 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6release_x86_64 x86_64 '
    config_args='-de -Dprefix=/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3 -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -Dusethreads -DDEBUGGING -Dusemultiplicity -Aeval:scriptdir=/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include',
    optimize='-O3 -g',
    cppflags='-fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -DDEBUGGING -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -I/opt/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 cc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib /opt/local/lib /usr/lib
    libs=-lgdbm -ldbm -ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    perllibs=-ldl -lm -lutil -lc
    libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=false, libperl=libperl.a
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags=' -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib -L/opt/local/lib -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: DEBUGGING HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV
                        PERL_TRACK_MEMPOOL USE_64_BIT_ALL USE_64_BIT_INT
                        USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES USE_LOCALE
                        USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Jan  5 2014 12:57:57
  %ENV:
    PERLBREW_BASHRC_VERSION="0.67"
    PERLBREW_HOME="/Users/nemo/.perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_MANPATH="/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/man"
    PERLBREW_PATH="/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/bin"
    PERLBREW_PERL="perl-5.16.3"
    PERLBREW_ROOT="/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew"
    PERLBREW_VERSION="0.67"
  @INC:
    /Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/site_perl/5.16.3
    /Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3
    .
```

Output from t/checkver.t

```
$ perl -Mblib t/00checkver.t
1..3
ok 1    loading
ok 2    new
OS: darwin
Perl version: 5.016003

Term::ReadLine::Gnu version: 1.20
GNU Readline Library version: 6.2
ok 3    done
panic: free from wrong pool, 686372612f62696c!=7fd3db000000 during global destruction.
```

GCC:

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

perlbrew

```
$ perlbrew version
/Users/nemo/perl5/perlbrew/bin/perlbrew  - App::perlbrew/0.67
```

others:

- using macports for some libraries and utilities.  macports are selfupdated and all ports are upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As linked in the question, the answer is *already* in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3298436/771480). Run:

```
 perlbrew install perl-5.16.3 --thread --multi --64all --debug --clang -Accflags="-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV"
```

and with this perl will get a successful installation:

```
$ cpanm Term::ReadLine::Gnu
--> Working on Term::ReadLine::Gnu
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAYASHI/Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.20.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.20 ... OK
Building and testing Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.20 ... 
Term::ReadLine::Gnu version: 1.20
GNU Readline Library version: 6.2
OK
Successfully installed Term-ReadLine-Gnu-1.20
1 distribution installed
```

In daxim's answer nowhere stated than the `-Accflags` works for `perlbrew` too. Really need read `perlbrew help` where is clearly stated:

```
-D,-U,-A       Switches passed to perl Configure script.
```

Anyway, still don't underdtand why for OS X is the `-Accflags="-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV"` not an **default**, but the lessons learned:

For OS X when build perl with perlbrew, an *ordinary user* **should use**

```
perlbrew -Accflags="-DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV"`
```

to getting an *working perl*.